# Can I grant limited mailbox access to an app-only application?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**In brief:** can I give my Azure application access to a limited set of mailboxes while still using the Client Credentials Flow (no signed in user)?

**More detail**

In Azure I have an app-only type application; by this I mean I will authenticate to it using the [Client Credentials Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) which means there is no signed-in user present.

Once authenticated I will acquire a token to access Microsoft Graph. I want to use Graph to access a limited set of Office365 mailboxes.

As far as I understand, I can use the admin-only Mail.Read permission scope for this, but this gives my application access to every user mailbox. I would prefer to avoid such broad access.

I think if I used delegated permissions instead, I could use the Mail.Read.Shared scope which would allow my application to read mailboxes that are shared with the signed in user, but then I can't use the Client Credentials Flow because I need to sign in a user, which is what I'm trying to avoid. This is an application which doesn't logically run in the context of a user. (The mailboxes I want to read are all shared, they aren't user mailboxes)

I'm a total Azure noob so I hope this makes sense.

**Is this question in the right place?**

I'm not sure. On the one hand, there are about 100 azure question in [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), but there are over 54k on SO, and that's not including sub tags.

On the other hand, I haven't included anything about programming in this question, although it is certainly a programming issue for me, insofar as I have to write the code to authenticate with Azure, get the token, and then access the Graph API, and the answer to this question will probably influence how I go about that. FWIW, here's how I'm currently authenticating and getting a token in C#:

```
var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0";
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", clientCredential).Result.AccessToken;
```

Although I do plan to change that to use a certificate rather than a secret.

If there is a better place for my question (whether stackexchange or other), please do let me know.

Comment: Organizations indeed tend to dedicate user accounts/inboxes to a specific subject or department. The concept of a 'user' being personal is therefor being violated. Typical theory v.s. reality-stuff. The use case described in the question is *very* familiar though; makes me wonder if a wholly different approach would be required here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App permissions are always organization-wide. The good thing for them is that using Client Creds is relatively simple and reliable. Revoking them would require deleting the role assignment or deleting the service principal entirely. But the bad side is that you cannot limit what it can access.

With delegated permissions, you could make a small web front-end, which allows users to login and give permissions to read their mail.
Your app can then store the user's refresh token securely and use that to access their mail whenever.
The good side is that this limits access to only those users who explicitly give permissions.
The bad side is this requires more work and is not as reliable, since refresh tokens get revoked if a user's password changes (for example).
And you must make sure you store the new refresh token you get when acquiring a token with the older refresh token.

TL;DR: There is no "right" answer to this. Both approaches have pros and cons, and neither is perfect. If your app cannot handle losing access for a while, then you must use app permissions.

Comment: Yep,agree to this answer.  if you choose to use client credentials flow, you need to accept this suitation.

Comment: Thank you. I was worried that I was missing something, so it's nice to have my understanding confirmed.

Comment: If I use the Authorization Code Flow instead, once I have the token/refresh token pair, can I then continue to obtain new token pairs (using the refresh tokens) indefinitely without having to authenticate again? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) seems to imply that I can.

Comment: Yes, basically that is correct. But the refresh token can get revoked, so you need to be prepared for that.

Comment: @juunas: Thanks